# Run commands at a specified time

Tags: bash

I learn the command `at` schedule to run a script at a specified time

```
at -f -m ./test.sh now + 10 minutes
```

How could I use `at` to schedule a `command`?

Suppose the situation,

I search all the musics but running silently on background

`find / -name *.mp3 1> ~/desktop/all_musics.md 2>/dev/null &`

I intent to open `all_musics.md` ten minutes later automatically.

`open all_music.md at now + 10 minutes`

Is it possible to get it done?

Comment: How do you plan to "open" your list of mp3?

Answer (score 0):

at takes input on standard in:

```
$ echo 'find / -name *.mp3 > ~/desktop/all_musics.md 2>/dev/null' | at now + 10 minutes
```

Comment: you should be a genius.

Comment: it is not working.

Comment: It works for me:
`$ echo 'touch /tmp/by-at' | at now + 1 minutes
job 8 at 2018-10-31 14:41
$ ls /tmp/by-at
ls: /tmp/by-at: No such file or directory
$ sleep 60; ls /tmp/by-at
/tmp/by-at
$`

Can you be more specific about what isn't working, and what is/isn't happening?

Answer (score 0):

`find /` to search all files in your entire system is not efficient, you should narrow down your search path.

Assume:

- Your mp3 search path is `~/Downloads/misc/mp3/`
- find result save to playlist path `~/Downloads/misc/mp3/my_mp3.list`
- Your system running gnome desktop environment
- `mpv` player installed in your system.

You can run this one-liner command:

```
sudo service atd start;
(find ~/Downloads/misc/mp3/ -type f -iname '*.mp3' -print0 2>/dev/null >~/Downloads/misc/mp3/my_mp3.list &);
echo 'export "XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP=GNOME";
export "GNOME_DESKTOP_SESSION_ID=this-is-deprecated";
export "DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS=unix:path=/run/user/1000/bus";
export "DISPLAY=:0";
cat ~/Downloads/misc/mp3/my_mp3.list | xargs -0 mpv --player-operation-mode=pseudo-gui' | at now + 1 minute
```

Explanation:

- `sudo service atd start;` start `atd` daemon, in case the deamon not run yet.
- `at now + 1 minute` doesn't means play audio after one minute, but it means play in next minute of current minute, so the elapse time is actually less than or equal to 1 minute.
- Ensures provide full path since `at` task will `cd` to the original path when specify `at` that time. It will not works if your target relative path not that path. You will know this if you do `at -c <pending_job_number>` to query the shell script content. Run `atq` to know the pending jobs number.
- `( 2>/dev/null &);` trick can suppress any extra output to your terminal.
- `-print0` and `xargs -0` together make the filename playable even though contains newline special character.
- You need `--player-operation-mode=pseudo-gui` since mp3 is audio only and no video gui popup by default to let you control. And don't put `xargs -o`, it will not works in `atd`.
- `XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP`, `GNOME_DESKTOP_SESSION_ID`, `DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS`, and `DISPLAY` are important environment variables in GNOME desktop environment to make some gui applications work correctly and able to display. For `mpv` to play mp3, the critical variable is `DISPLAY`.

Just like other daemon such as cron, `atd` also lack of environment variables to make gui application works correctly, as described in `man at`:

> For both at and batch, commands are read from standard input or the
>   file specified with the -f option and executed.  The working
>   directory, the environment (except for the variables BASH_VERSINFO,
>   **DISPLAY**, EUID, GROUPS, SHELLOPTS, TERM, UID, and _) and  the  umask 
>   are  retained from the time of invocation

**DISPLAY** might not enough for other GUI applications, in that case, to figure out environment variables required for your program in your system without dig into  source code:

1. Run `declare -p > /tmp/d.sh` to save attributes and values of environment variable name. `env > /tmp/d.sh` will remove quotes and not suitable to direct
   re-use， that's the reason I suggest to use `declare -p > /tmp/d.sh`.
2. Save this in your `/tmp/test.sh`:

   ```
   . /tmp/d.sh
   mpv --player-operation-mode=pseudo-gui foo.mp3
   ```
3. And test that script continuously. If it able to play correctly， narrow down by delete half of `/tmp/d.sh`； or else undo the deleted content and try delete another part. But ensures don't delete half of `declare` statement. And you no need to delete `DISPLAY` which normally required by GUI application.

   `env -i bash /tmp/test.sh`
4. Eventually you able to get critical env var(s) for your program.
   The concept is `env -i` removed all environment variables， then
   source your remaining environment variables.
5. This method doesn't guarantee all functions work correctly, e.g. program slow to startup, since some function may requires different variables. You need repeat the steps to figure out for that function.

In addition, don't forget the existent of `sleep` command:

```
( (find ~/Downloads/misc/mp3/ -type f -iname '*.mp3' -print0 2>/dev/null >~/Downloads/misc/mp3/my_mp3.list) & pid=$!; sleep 600; kill -9 $pid 2>/dev/null; cat ~/Downloads/misc/mp3/my_mp3.list | xargs -0 mpv --player-operation-mode=pseudo-gui) &
```