# Schedule a command to execute minutes later

Tags: osx, at

I tried to schedule a command to execute 2 minutes later

`at -c "ls -l" now + 2 minutes`

It fails with multiple ways

```
$ echo "open 'Google Chrome' " | at now + 2 minutes
job 15 at Mon Oct 29 13:31:42 2018
```

How could I enable it working?

```
run "open 'Google Chrome' "  at now + 2 minutes
```

I tried, it is not working

```
$ at now 
at>ls -l
at>^D
at> <EOT>

job 18 at Mon Oct 29 15:55:00 2018
```

Comment: "_It fails with multiple ways_" - please provide specific errors rather then a general statement.

Comment: Is this on a Mac?

Comment: yes, this is on Mac @roaima

Comment: "_it is not working_" how do you know it isn't working? What do you think should happen? What did you observe happening? What have you done about the discrepancy to try and resolve it?

Comment: Please do not post [duplicates](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/478336/run-commands-at-a-specified-time).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Run commands at a specified time](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/478336/run-commands-at-a-specified-time)

Comment: If you're on a mac, probably the least irritating way is just to do something like `bash -c "sleep 60 && actual command" &`. If you want it to persist even if you hang up the connection, consider also putting it in `screen` or `tmux`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You misunderstand what the `-c` option does. This option prints out the contents of the temporary file which is created by the `at` command when a new `at` job is created.

Here is one way to create a simple `at` job:

```
$ at now + 2 minutes
at> ls -l
at> CTRL-D     <---- Press Control Key + D Key simultaniously
at> <EOT>
job 2 at Mon Oct 29 03:34:00 2018
$
```

And here is the contents of the temporary file created by `at` for thie job:

```
$ at -c 2
#!/bin/sh
# atrun uid=1000 gid=1000
# mail student 0
umask 2
XDG_VTNR=1; export XDG_VTNR
SSH_AGENT_PID=3010; export SSH_AGENT_PID
XDG_SESSION_ID=1; export XDG_SESSION_ID
.... lots more environment ....
cd /home/student || {
     echo 'Execution directory inaccessible' >&2
     exit 1
}
${SHELL:-/bin/sh} << 'marcinDELIMITER689a131f'
ls -l

marcinDELIMITER689a131f
$
```

Comment: ty, I tried but not works as intended.

Comment: @Sawajiri then please edit your question to tell us what you intend.

Comment: @Sawajiri. Exactly what did not work in the able example?