# Install the latest version of GNU at?

Tags: bash, osx

I updated my bash to latest version and install the coreutils, but the command `at` is still the old-fashion version

```
BSD General Commands Manual
at, batch, atq, atrm -- queue, examine, or delete jobs for later execution
January 13, 2002
```

Additionally, `gat` is not installed

```
$ which gat
which: no gat i
$ shtool at
/usr/local/bin/shtool:Error: unknown command `at'
/usr/local/bin/shtool:Hint:  run `/usr/local/bin/shtool -h' for usage
```

How could I install the latest GNU version of `at`,
I searched "bash source code command at" or similar, get no desired info returned.

I raise the question, because I asked three identically question about set timer for a command,

> [bash - Run commands at a specified time - Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/478336/run-commands-at-a-specified-time)
>
> [bash - Found files and set autotask to check it later with commands - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53058434/found-files-and-set-autotask-to-check-it-later-with-commands)
>
> [osx - Schedule a command to execute minutes later - Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/478348/schedule-a-command-to-execute-minutes-later)

However, I cannot reproduce the result of all the answer.

I cannot reproduce the following answer:

```
find / -regex '.*\.pdf$' 2>/dev/null 1>found.md
echo 'export DISPLAY=:0; code found.md' | at now + 10min

echo "code found.md" | at now + 30 minutes
```

and

```
           at −m 0730 tomorrow
           sort < file >outfile
           EOT
```

from the manual page [at.1p - Linux manual page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/at.1p.html)

Comment: What Unix are you using and what package manager on that Unix are you installing things with? Also mention why you would want to install another version of this tool.

Comment: I use brew. `$ brew search crontab
No formula or cask found for "crontab".`  "brew search at " return many unrelated stuff. @Kusalananda

Comment: $ uname the os version is 
Darwin

Comment: It is still unclear what it is that you can not do with macOS `at` that you would be able to do with some other implementation of the tool.

Comment: BTW, most Unices uses Vixie Cron (both macOS and e.g. Ubuntu does). While there exists a GNU-licensed cron daemon ([mcron](https://www.gnu.org/software/mcron/)), I have never seen it in any wider use.

Comment: ty, please have a look of my edit.@Kusalananda

Comment: Your issue seems to be with the usage of `at`. All answers to the linked questions point to the fact that you are using it wrong. `at` reads the commands that it should execute from its standard input, not from the command line.

Comment: `echo 'export DISPLAY=:0; code found.md' | at now + 10min`  in one answer [bash - Found files and set autotask to check it later with commands - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53058434/found-files-and-set-autotask-to-check-it-later-with-commands) @Kusalananda

Comment: from the pipeline to get stdin @Kusalananda

Comment: also `at −m 0730 tomorrow
               sort < file >outfile
               EOT

` from  [at.1p - Linux manual page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/at.1p.html)

Comment: That _particular_ sequence is `at -m 0730 tomorrow` followed by pressing `Enter` and then interactively entering the `sort` command, pressing `Enter` again, and then pressing `Ctrl+D` which is what `EOT` means.  This is what meant by "at a terminal".

Comment: ty, could you please transmit the comment to answer. @Kusalananda